# Зависает и закрывается приложение при добавлении функции update()

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, update, paintevent

При добавлении функции `self.update()` зависает и почти сразу же закрывается приложение.

Эта функция нужна для перерисовки места положения квадратов в будущем

```
from typing import Sized
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRadialGradient, QPainter, QPainterPath, QPen, QBrush, QGradient, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPointF, Qt, QRect
import sys
import time

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.resize(600, 400)

       
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.painter = QPainter(self)
        
        radialGrad = QRadialGradient(QPointF(300, 450), 200)
        
        radialGrad.setColorAt(0, QColor('#1B2735'))
        radialGrad.setColorAt(1, QColor('#090A0F'))

        self.painter.setBrush(radialGrad)
        self.painter.drawRect(0, 0, 600, 400) 

        self.painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.white))

        self.painter.drawRect(100, 390, 2, 2) 
        self.painter.drawRect(200, 390, 3, 3) 
        self.painter.drawRect(300, 390, 4, 4)
        self.update()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick добавил минимальный воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замкните все `self.painter` на `painter`

Нельзя использовать `time.sleep(1)` - это блокирует интерфейс.

Нельзя использовать `self.update()` в методе `paintEvent()`. 
`update()` используется вне этого метода и для того чтобы вызвать этот метод `paintEvent()`.

```
import sys
from typing import Sized
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRadialGradient, QPainter, QPainterPath, QPen, QBrush, QGradient, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPointF, Qt, QRect

#import time


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.resize(600, 400)
       
    def paintEvent(self, event):
#        self.painter = QPainter(self)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        
        radialGrad = QRadialGradient(QPointF(300, 450), 200)
        
        radialGrad.setColorAt(0, QColor('#1B2735'))
        radialGrad.setColorAt(1, QColor('#090A0F'))

        painter.setBrush(radialGrad)
        painter.drawRect(0, 0, 600, 400) 

        painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt.white))

        painter.drawRect(100, 390, 2, 2) 
        painter.drawRect(200, 390, 3, 3) 
        painter.drawRect(300, 390, 4, 4)

#        self.update()
#        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста почему нельзя так писать self.painter

Comment: @helldrg вам не надо делать его экземпляром класса, сделали перерисовку когда вам надо вызвав self.update() и забыли про него.

Comment: Вывел update в отдельный поток все равно закрывается форма =( Поток создаю в инициализации класса

Comment: @helldrg  нельзя взаимодействовать из дополнительного потока с виджетами основного потока.

Comment: Есть какие-нибудь варианты выполнять функцию paintEvent раз 30 в секунду без зависания интерфейса?

Comment: @helldrg задайте новый вопрос и приложите свой код.